# Testing an injectionToken with jest / angular don't work

Tags: angular, jestjs

i have a service

```
import { HUNT_SERVICE } from '../../home/home.module';

@Injectable()

export class SupportsService {

    private listOfScannedSupports: Observable<PortableObjectResult>[] = [];

    constructor(@Inject (HUNT_SERVICE) private huntService: IHuntService) {}
```

Which use an injectionToken defines and provided like this :

```
export const HUNT_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<IHuntService>('HuntService');
...
  providers: [
    {
        provide: HUNT_SERVICE,
        useClass: HuntService
    },
    SupportsService
  ]
```

It works well.

I tried to test the SupportsService in Jest like this :

```
import { HUNT_SERVICE } from '../../home/home.module';
import { SupportsService } from './supports.service';

describe('SupportsService', () => {
    let supportsServiceTest: SupportsService;
    let huntService: IHuntService;

    const mockHuntService = {
        startHuntThenReadPortableObject: jest.fn(query => mockPortableObjectReturn),
    };

    beforeEach(
        waitForAsync(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    SupportsService,
                    { provide: HUNT_SERVICE, useValue: mockHuntService },
                ],
            }).compileComponents();
        }),
      );

    beforeEach(() => {
        supportsServiceTest = TestBed.inject(SupportsService);
        huntService = TestBed.inject(HUNT_SERVICE);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(supportsServiceTest).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

when i launch the test i have this error :

```
src/renderer/app/features/supports/services/supports.service.spec.ts (7.707 s)
  ● SupportsService › should be created

    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[SupportsService -> undefined -> undefined]:
      NullInjectorError: No provider for undefined!

      at NullInjector.Object.<anonymous>.NullInjector.get (../packages/core/src/di/injector_compatibility.ts:246:21)
```

I don't understand what i missed !!!

Comment: I'm sure the OP has figured it out already. Yet it can still happen for someone else. So in case it helps - most probably the problem is with circular dependencies in your code. "undefined" in the injection chain is a good indicator of it - webpack fails to properly resolve the import and a dependency remains "undefined". So, in turns, Angular fails to inject such a dependency